# Best way to handle data streams for non-sealed trait hierarchies

Tags: scala, apache-flink

I know that for ADTs (sealed traits) there are some ongoing efforts to overcome the performance degradation caused by the kryo fallback (see https://github.com/apache/flink/pull/12929). E.g.,

```scala
sealed trait Event {
  def id: Int
}
case class Pageview(id: Int, page: String) extends Event
case class Click(id: Int, url: String) extends Event
```

However, is there anything one can do for handling a similar situation but for `unsealed` traits? That is, imagine a situation where `Event` is not sealed because you don't know in advance which specific events you will be dealing with, or maybe you are working on a generic framework that will be used to develop specific applications afterwards, each one dealing with a set of particular events. So, basically, the trait cannot be sealed. Instead of simple case classes like `Pageview` and `Click`, within each specific application one could be dealing with auto-generated case classes from protocol buffer definitions, in a system which should be able to add more types of events into the mix, so to speak.

To be clear, the main idea would be to define the "general framework" in
terms of `DataStream[Event]`, where `Event` would be a trait capturing the
required commonalities. Within each specific application, one would work
with different types of events but would ultimately perform a union in order to combine them in a `DataStream[Event]`.

How should one address this problem, if serialization performance wants to be optimized? The general advice is not to use Flink with heterogenous types to start with, because it will not be able to derive efficient serializers. But the described use case sounds legit to me, so what would be the best way to handle it, or, to put it another way, how to minimize performance degradation due to serialization?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options:

- Implement your own serializer: This serializer has a dictionary of possible types and encodes this type through it. This is also somewhat similar to using Kryo with registered classes, but you can use more performant serializers for the payload.
- Generify your framework - ideally with reified types: You write your shared code once, but it's applied in a very specific way for each application. This doesn't work well with the final union however. It's more applicable for joint steps shared across different applications (validation, data cleaning, sinks).
- Rethink your data model: If the events are eventually written to Kafka or Pulsar, you need to make it application-independent anyways. You could use an [envelope format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59466651/how-to-manage-many-avsc-files-in-flink-when-consuming-multiple-topics-gracefully/59473498#59473498). It's less dynamic, but for serious applications, I have found the schema-first approach to work better (better schema compability, faster, clearer APIs=schema to other teams).

Comment: Well, in my case the different event types are already in Kafka. They correspond to protocol buffer generated case classes. What I want is a way to normalize all of them somehow and then combine (union) all the different data streams into one for unified data processing based on some common required fields. What I am doing now is to adapt each specific type of event to comply with the `Event` trait. So, I am wrapping the original events into classes which implement the common interface based on the underlying (original) events' data (which would be the payload so to speak).